# Multiple staff Mouse Cursor Losing Focus / Keyboard Dropping while typing

Tags: group-policy, cursor, mouse-cursor, logitech-keyboard, window-focus

Issue: For months, many in our staff have been dealing with a problem described as:

Where, and When, we are typing- the keyboard drops / mouse cursor loses focus, and we have to actually click back into where (the area) we are typing in. Yaaaarrg (groan) ! :)

For example, I am typing this question right now and when this problem occurs- I might continue to type this sentence, but only to realize that the keyboard dropped out / the mouse cursor lost focus- and have to 'go back in' and click in the middle of the word or something and type most everything again.

We have exhausted many forums (including older / similar ones from this community) to troubleshoot!

Okay! So what have we done so far (as the IT department) to try and resolve this issue? And then, what are we leaning toward for the culprit (Dongle itself or location thereof [the dongle in a docking station port vs. direct usb port on computer to motherboard], Low Batteries, Docking station firmware update or faulty docks, Device Manger/ Driver issue, Mouse settings in windows settings, GPO design error, a conflict of sorts between GPOs, a problem with one of our GPOs failing or getting an error somewhere when it tries to apply)? :

Moving the wireless dongle from docking station port to a direct motherboard usb port does not solve.

Wired keyboards and wired mouses have not resolved.

Driver updates have not solved.. whether they are for the input devices or even the chipset or firmware (Device manager. Dell Command Update, Windows update).

BIOS updates. settings, and USB Thunderbolt Boot support has not solved.

Windows mouse settings have so far proven to no avail- including scroll inactive windows while hovering toggle both ways.

We have tried to Disable certain GPOs and revisited our GPOs -- also have tried observing the mouse function (pointer) while having a CMD window open and updating / disabling / applying certain policies with live observation of workstation and trying to see if we can narrow down which policy could be responsible.

Yes, there are times we observe on certain computers 'Group Policy Scheduled Tasks' failed due to an error.

We believe that the culprit lies in GPO somewhere and can be fixed. We use WINDOWS 10 and WINDOWS 11 (22H2 w/11, 21 H2 & 22H2 w/10). We use Dell Precision laptops mainly for all staff. Thank you all!

Comment: Something is stealing focus. Run Microsoft's Process Explorer program to monitor what is running when it happens. Look for quick flashes and keep an eye out for e.g. `werfault.exe`. If you see that, something (perhaps a driver) is crashing and reloading. If you are using remote IT software (Take Control Agent etc) or employee monitoring software. test with it disabled.

Comment: Look for malware -- do a *thorough* check on one PC.